# Convert SurfaceImageSource to PNG

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, directx

I have an image SurfaceImageSource and I would convert it to PNG.
I tried to use this project:
[link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/How-to-save-SurfaceImageSou-8668a455#content)

I tried to use SharpDX library, but I did not succeed.

```
                 private void initialize()
                 {
                        StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("folder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                        StorageFile imagePng = await folder.CreateFileAsync("file.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                        if (imagePng != null)
                        {
                            //surfaceImageSource to PNG method
                            surfaceToPng(surfaceImage,imagePng);
                        }
                 }

                 private void surfaceToPng(SurfaceImageSource surface,StorageFile imagePng){
                        IRandomAccessStream stream = await imagePng.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

                           //.....//
                 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/How-to-save-SurfaceImageSou-8668a455#content) you linked is about "How to save SurfaceImageSource target as an image in Universal app" which is just what you want. It create a C++ [Windows Runtime Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/index) named "MyImageSourceComponent" and provide a sealed class named "MyImageSource" which contains the method `public void SaveSurfaceImageToFile(IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream);` You can call this method to save the [SurfaceImageSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.surfaceimagesource.aspx) to png.

```
 uint imageWidth;
 uint imageHeight;
 MyImageSource myImageSource;
 public MainPage()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent();

     imageWidth = (uint)this.MyImage.Width;
     imageHeight = (uint)this.MyImage.Height;
     myImageSource = new MyImageSource(imageWidth, imageHeight, true);
     this.MyImage.Source = myImageSource;
 }

 private async void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {   
     FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
     savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Png file", new List<string>() { ".png" });
     savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
     StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
     if (file != null)
     {
         IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
         myImageSource.SaveSurfaceImageToFile(stream);
     }
 }
```

Although this sample is for Windows 8.1, it also should be able work with uwp app. I helped convert the sample into uwp app [here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/CSurfaceImageSource) you can reference. I created a new uwp app with a windows runtime component and reference the code of the "MyImageSouceComponent" in the sample. Then add the runtime component as reference to the uwp project. At last use the above code call the `SaveSurfaceImageToFile` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. My problem is that: I already have an image of SurfaceImageSource type. In your code you create and draw a new image of MyImageSource type. I should turn my SurfaceImageSource image into MyImageSource to use the method  SaveSurfaceImageToFile for my image. but I not succeed.